# jQuery Accordion HTML Arrow Flip

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a simple jQuery accordion with arrows on the section titles that point down when the section is closed and point up when the section is open. Unfortunately, when a section is currently clicked all arrows are switching to up and staying that way. I can't quite figure out how to combat this problem.

JQuery

```
function AccordionSelectionClickHandler(panelSelector, openCloseSelector)
{
//Get a handle to the list of panels
var allPanels = $(panelSelector);
//Specify the click handler for elements that open or close the accordion panels

$('.arrow').html("&darr;");
$(openCloseSelector).click(function ()
{
    //Close all of the panels
    allPanels.slideUp();

    //Check to see if the slide is already open
    if ($(this).parent().next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        // if it is not, open it
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown('normal');
    }

    // fix this arrow to select a single arrow
    $('.arrow').html("&uarr;");
    return false;
});
}
```

(where `panelSelector` selects the accordion and `openCloseSelector` selects the panel to open/close)

HTML

```
<dl class="accordion">

<dt><a href="">Panel 1</a>
<span class="arrow"></span></dt>
<dd>Conttent</dd>

<dt><a href="">Panel 2</a>
<span class="arrow"></span></dt>
<dd>Conntent</dd>

<dt><a href="">Panel 3</a>
<span class="arrow"></span></dt>
<dd>Content</dd>

</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.arrow').html("&uarr;");` try `$(this).find('.arrow').html("&uarr;");`. This way, you're making the jQuery find the `.arrow` within the `openCloseSelector` you're clicking on.

I would also suggest putting `$(this).find('.arrow').html("&uarr;");` inside the `if` statement so the arrow's text changes depending on the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think we'll do it slightly different way by using an arrow image in the background of a 'dt' tag and changing its position on clicked. I have done some work for you to understand.

click on this link to view an example.
    
       `JS Fiddle example`

Also make sure that you uncomment the css when you have an arrow image.

Hope that helps.